# Why does my site seems to load so much faster on FireFox than Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, performance

I'm developing a site here: [ferdinand-henry.com](http://ferdinand-henry.com/) and for some strange reason, the site seems to load so much faster in FireFox than Chrome.

For example, FireFox loads in 2-3 seconds and Chrome loads in 10 seconds.

The site also loads really fast when I'm in Chrome Incognito mode. I've read online that it has something to do with my cache and extensions, but I've already disabled all my extensions and cleared all cache and it still loads slowly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your site only loads 0.30 seconds faster in Firefox. Check your console > network for the loading speed. It might look like it loads faster, but it really isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think it mostly depends on the interprter engine in browser which responsible for interpreting th scripts which server sends to your browser and another thing about firefox as you have mentioned the extension in firefox is also responsible for it and another thing which i think matters a lot the developement of the browser as you can see chrome has same UI on all windows/linux/mac since it is mostly written in java so it requires JVM to run hence it is slow as compared to firefox which is written separately for each OS using the respective Oss' APIs hence it is fast since it directly interacts with OS than interacting with JVM which in turn interacts with OS like in case of chrome.still chrome is faster in Incognito mode because of its intelligence to keep frequently data cached if you ll see the temporary files created by chrome they are huge in size as compared to that of firefox.